# How to do TDD with Typescript in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, angular, karma-jasmine, visual-studio-code

I want to setup **TDD** in **Visual Studio Code** for **typescript**. I am working on an **angular2** application and i am writing my code in typescript. How can  i setup Visual Studio Code so that it runs **Karma** as well as **Typescript compiler** in the background and the results are shown in the output window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TDD - is just a concept of development.

So the answer for your question - you need to create configuration for your building tools which take care of your testing for VSC. Here - [VS Code tasks configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) you can find guide, how to integrate such building tools like Grunt or Gulp with VS Code.

But if you don't have building process yet you need first of all create all stuff which will help you in Test Driven Development. So you need watcher which looks at your code and run particular test once code changed. There different ways to do that, hope this small article will move you ahead.